# Cosmos DB - Query for newest document of select partitions?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, greatest-n-per-group, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Consider a CosmosDB container with the following document model:

```json
{
  id: <string>,
  userId: <string>, // partition key
  data: <string>
}
```

I have a need to provide a query with N user ids and get the newest document for each one.

So for example, if I have this data in the container:

```json
{ id: '1', userId: 'user1', data: 'a', _ts: 1 },
{ id: '2', userId: 'user1', data: 'b', _ts: 2 },
{ id: '3', userId: 'user2', data: 'c', _ts: 10 },
{ id: '4', userId: 'user2', data: 'd', _ts: 5 },
{ id: '5', userId: 'user3', data: 'e', _ts: 3 },
{ id: '6', userId: 'user3', data: 'f', _ts: 4 },
{ id: '7', userId: 'user4', data: 'g', _ts: 100 },
{ id: '8', userId: 'user4', data: 'h', _ts: 99 },
{ id: '9', userId: 'user5', data: 'i', _ts: 1 },
{ id: '10', userId: 'user5', data: 'j', _ts: 2 },
```

I want to do something like this:

```
-- This doesn't work
SELECT c.userId, (SELECT TOP 1 d.id, d.data WHERE d.userId = c.userId FROM d ORDER BY d._ts DESC) AS newest
WHERE c.userId IN ['user1', 'user2', 'user4', 'user5']
```

To get this result:

```json
{ userId: 'user1', newest: { id: '2', data: 'b' } },
{ userId: 'user2', newest: { id: '3', data: 'c' } },
{ userId: 'user4', newest: { id: '7', data: 'g' } },
{ userId: 'user5', newest: { id: '10', data: 'j' } },
```

From what I can tell, JOIN in CosmosDB cannot be used to filter correlated documents. Is there still a way to accomplish this? I am open to using a stored procedure, but from what I can tell execution of a stored procedure can only occur on a specific partition given it's key. In my case, the primary grouping is the partition key.

I have considered a fan-out request approach, but I might be querying for 50 to 100 user ids at a time in the query. In that case it might be faster to just get all documents in each partition and when iterating only keep the newest -- but that's a large paged response to sift through.

My final thought is I could use ASB/EventGrid/Function and another dependent CosmosDB container to always clone the most recent updated document every time a document is updated, but it seems like overkill. Surely there is a way to construct a query to do what I want?

Thanks

Comment: `select value max(c._ts) from c group by c.userId` can get a list of timestamp in each user newest column.

Comment: It's likely going to be an expensive query even if there is a way. My hunch is to use change feed to keep a latest item by user in a separate container for optimized reads.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea like

```
select c._ts from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS((select value max(c._ts) from c group by c.userId), c._ts)
```

But it can't get the result because `select value max(c._ts) from c group by c.userId` doesn't be recognized as an array, and if I use `Array(select value max(c._ts) from c group by c.userId)` instead, it returns all items.

So how about execute sql twice?

Get the timestamp array first :`select value max(c._ts) from c where c.userId in ('user1','user2') group by c.userId`
,

and then copy the result as the input to use array_contains function:

```
select c._ts,c.data from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS([1623306298,1623306259,1623306217], c._ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use the following approach.

```
SELECT t.userid, 
       SUBSTRING(t.concat, 28,8000) AS data
FROM 
(
SELECT  c.userid,
        MAX(CONCAT(TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000),c.data)) AS concat
FROM c
WHERE c.userid IN ('user1', 'user2')
GROUP BY c.userid
) AS t
```

which returns a result like

```
[
    {
        "userid": "user1",
        "data": "b"
    },
    {
        "userid": "user2",
        "data": "d"
    }
]
```

The derived table `t` returns results like the following...

```
[
    {
        "userid": "user2",
        "concat": "2021-06-11T17:42:03.0000000Zd"
    },
    {
        "userid": "user1",
        "concat": "2021-06-11T17:41:41.0000000Zb"
    }
]
```

The document with the highest `_ts` per user will have the lexicographically highest datetime prefix in the concatenated string and the ancillary data that is appended on behind it is extracted with `SUBSTRING`.

It should be able to use the index for the `WHERE` clause - but then will need to look at all documents for the given `userid`s (so if there are many documents per user doing separate `TOP 1` queries for each one would likely be much better)

Comment: *The document with the highest _ts per user will have the lexicographically highest datetime prefix in the concatenated string and the ancillary data that is appended on behind it is extracted with SUBSTRING.* - Though do be aware that the `_ts` value is only to the second, so depending on how quickly your data updates, you can have multiple items with the same `_ts` value.