# Azure COSMOS DB get top from each match

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, greatest-n-per-group, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is is possible to have a single query for the below queries.

```
Select top 1* from f
where f.test.id = '1'
order by f.time desc
```

And

```
Select top 1* from f
where f.test.id = '2'
order by f.time desc
```

Because the below query return the top 1 from the combined list but instead in my case it should return two response one for each id. Any leads ?

```
Select top 1* from f
where f.test.id in ('1','2')
order by f.time desc
```

Comment: From what you're showing it doesn't seem like the two queries are related - give me the latest of one thing and the latest of another thing. If the timelines are separate, it doesn't seem like you can ask a single question.

Comment: If you are after the single latest item by ID, you could maintain a materialized view with only the latest item for each ID. Then a single query would guarantee returning only 1 item per ID.

Comment: There is no such query where you can get the *top n* for different values. You might want to consider periodic aggregation to keep track of such "top" items (whether via materialized view, as @NoahStahl suggested, or by another mechanism).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67914357/73226