# CosmoDB equivalent of this SQL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What's a good cosmodb sql equivalent to this? I have almost identical sql working on a dummy table in postgres, but can't seem to replicate it on cosmodb.

```sql
SELECT c.device_id FROM c
    WHERE (c.timestamp, c.device_id)
        IN (
            SELECT c.device_id, MAX(c.timestamp) FROM c WHERE c.device_id in ('00137A100000D2DB', '00137A100000D299') GROUP BY c.device_id
        )
```

results in the error:

```
 Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":49,"end":50},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near ','."}]}
ActivityId: ef246154-4a6b-4657-9cb3-8437a793053e, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
```

sample document

```
{
    "device_id": "00137A100000D299",
    "timestamp": 1602127299000,
    "battery": 3.6,
    "battery_unit": "V",
    "temperature": 0.76,
    "temperature_unit": "°C",
    "humidity": 36.28,
    "humidity_unit": "%",
    "id": "87340b02-2a5d-48db-9dff-97a14785cb7f"
}
```

Basically the idea is to get the latest timestamp for some known device ids, then use that to get the latest data at that timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos DB SQL API does not allow any kind of lookups based on the result of a sub query or [cross document joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-join) (though lookups between documents *are* possible in the Mongo API and Graph API)  - so you would need to do one query from the client and then use the values from that in a second query.

Or potentially you could adjust the SQL in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914357/cosmos-db-query-for-newest-document-of-select-partitions/67943898#67943898) to do it all in a single aggregate query.

Comment: Could you add an example? So the query should just get the most recent row for each device_id

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @martin-smith, you can't do cross doc magic with single query except simple aggregation.

To add a more practical note, if you happen to have just a single data point per timestamp, then your simplest option would be do just do a simple ordered query per device:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM c
where c.device_id = @deviceId
order by timestamp desc
```

Quite often it cheaper and more maintainable to just send multiple simple and well-indexed queries than trying to optimize those 10ms requests to server by writing a complex SQL query.

Comment: Is there any way to efficiently do it in two queries? rather than "N" queries where "N" is the number of device_id's?

Iv'e been experimenting but it seems like without support for UNION ALL and various other functions there's no way do it in two queries efficiently other than using max operator which is not what i want because it does too much work.

Comment: I don't think there is anything simpler and/or with better RU usage with just 2 queries. IS there a reason you optimize number of queries? How big is this N on average?