# Select first item in each GROUP BY in Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have below json structure

```
  json1
  {
   name : Raju
   Location : bangloor
   _ts: 1705505722
  }
  json2
  {
   name : Ramu
   Location : bangloor
   _ts: 1705505725
  }
  json3
  {
   name : Ram
   Location : bangloor
   _ts: 1705505729
  }
  json4
  {
   name : sam
   Location : kerala
   _ts: 1705505830
  }
  json5
  {
   name : samual
   Location : kerala
   _ts: 1705505835
  }
  json6
  {
   name : ramya
   Location : kerala
   _ts: 1705505838
  }
```

I need to group by each item by location and take the latest json(based on created date with full json content) from each group

Expected Output:

```
[{
   name : Ram
   Location : bangloor
   _ts: 1705505729
 },
 {
  name : ramya
  Location : kerala
  _ts: 1705505838
}]
```

I have tried below query but it is not working

```sql
SELECT *
from c
JOIN (
 SELECT c1.Location, MAX(c1._ts) AS MaxTimestamp
 FROM c c1
 GROUP BY c1.Location) maxTimestamps
WHERE c.Location = maxTimestamps.Location 
AND c._ts = maxTimestamps.maxTimestamp
```

I think the non-correlated subqueries are not supported directly in Cosmos DB.Can we able to do this in a single query with self join.

Comment: Could you provide query which you have tried? So, it will be easy to understand your issue.

Comment: You can't do it with a self join as cross document joins are not supported.  If you only need a limited amount of details data from the document then one approach is a [concatenation approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943898/73226) to bundle it along with the timestamp. Otherwise you will need to send multiple queries - probably one to get the distinct list of locations and then one for each location to get the `LIMIT  1` for that (you could do your initial query and then do a second query for a specific `_ts` per location but this could be out of date and no longer the max by then)

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Smith suggested in comments, you can `concatenate` location along with `timestamp`, the same approach is used in the below answer:

```sql
SELECT c.Location,
MAX(CONCAT(TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000),' ',c.name)) 
AS timeName 
FROM c WHERE c.Location IN ('kerala', 'bangloor') GROUP  BY c.Location
```

`CONCAT()` function is used in the above query to concatenate location with the respected timestamp and `MAX()` function is used to retrieve maximum value from concatenated value.

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "Location": "kerala",
        "timeName": "2024-01-22T05:22:10.0000000Z ramya"
    },
    {
        "Location": "bangloor",
        "timeName": "2024-01-22T05:19:07.0000000Z Ram"
    }
]
```